# How can I improve the performance of this Google Sheets custom function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets project that uses this custom function 50-100 times, so I'm trying to make the function as efficient as possible. The function filters data that is written to the INPUT worksheet (via the Google API) and then draws a table for a subset of the data.

I have provided a working sample spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KVjDl0Ix2bnlPqPEnsY4wh34MIPeayDPk3cq7DdU3g4/edit?usp=sharing

The 'META' worksheet is simply to trigger the custom function to run (i.e. mimic the INPUT sheet being populated via the Google API) by changing the value in cell A1, which is an argument for the custom function call.

The 'INPUT' sheet contains sample input data. The greyed out columns (Group name, Field name, Type, Concatenated Id, VLookup value) are not used by the function:

| Instance Id | Group name | Group Id | Field name | Field Id | Type | Value | File Id | Role | Concatenated Id | VLookup value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance1A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 1 | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | CURRENCY | 100 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffcInstance1A | 100 |
| Instance1A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 2 | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | CURRENCY | 200 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8eInstance1A | 200 |
| Instance1A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 3 | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | CURRENCY | 300 | Pilot_File | Pilot | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260dInstance1A | 300 |
| Instance1B | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 1 | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | CURRENCY | 110 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffcInstance1B | 110 |
| Instance1B | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 2 | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | CURRENCY | 220 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8eInstance1B | 220 |
| Instance1B | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 3 | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | CURRENCY | 330 | Pilot_File | Pilot | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260dInstance1B | 330 |
| Instance2A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 1 | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | CURRENCY | 1000 | Co-PIlot_File | Co-Pilot | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffcInstance2A | 1000 |
| Instance2A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 2 | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | CURRENCY | 2000 | Co-PIlot_File | Co-Pilot | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8eInstance2A | 2000 |
| Instance2A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 3 | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | CURRENCY | 3000 | Co-PIlot_File | Co-Pilot | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260dInstance2A | 3000 |

The 'TABLE_CONFIG' sheet contains configuration attributes for the results table. The greyed out column (Description) is not used by the function:

| Field Id | Description | Desired table field column | Group Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | Field 1 | 1 | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 |
| 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | Field 2 | 2 | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 |
| ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | Field 3 | 3 | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 |

The 'RESULTS_Pilot' and 'RESULTS_Co-Pilot' sheets are examples of how the custom function is called from various places throughout the spreadsheet. The headers are static. The function is called like this:

```
=getTable("91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7", "TABLE_CONFIG", "Pilot", META!A1)
```

The results table must always be returned to display in the format shown in the sample:

| Instance Id | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | File Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance1A | 100 | 200 | 300 | Pilot_File |
| Instance1B | 110 | 220 | 330 | Pilot_File |

I am fairly new to coding and very new to Google Apps Script. The custom function is working, but I am hoping for tips on speeding it up, or pointers where my code is inefficient or redundant.

Thank you.

```
// Filters INPUT by Group Id and Role. Called from getTable().
function filterInput(group, role) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INPUT");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var results = [];
  values.forEach(function (row) {
    if (row[2] === group && row[8] === role) {
      results.push(row);
    }
  });
  return results;
}

// Builds matrix. Called from getTable().
let generateMatrix = function (m, n, value) {
  let matrix = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    let row = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      row.push(value);
    }
    matrix.push(row);
  }
  return matrix;
};

// Main function called from RESULTS_Pilot and RESULTS_Co-Pilot worksheets
function getTable(groupUUID, configSheetName, role) {
  // Filter INPUT tab to get only rows for group and role
  values = filterInput(groupUUID, role);
  // If filtered INPUT contains 0 rows, return empty string
  if (values.length === 0) {
    Logger.log("There are no matching rows in INPUT.");
    return ("");
  }
  else {
    Logger.log("There are " + values.length + " filtered rows for the specified group and role.");
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(configSheetName);
    var range = sheet.getDataRange();
    var configValues = range.getValues();
    var configFields = 0;
    var rowNum = 0;
    var uniqueInstanceRows = 0; // Need to find the number of unique instance rows (i.e. unique Instance Ids) to build table
    var colValues = []; // Create array with only first column values (Instance Ids) from filtered input rows
    for (i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      colValues.push(values[i][0]);
    }

    const unique = (value, index, self) => { return self.indexOf(value) === index; } // Get only unique Instance Ids from array
    var Unique_List = colValues.filter(unique);
    uniqueInstanceRows = Unique_List.length; // Will be used to build empty table using generateMatrix()
    Logger.log("# of unique Instance Id rows: " + uniqueInstanceRows);

    configValues.forEach(function (configRow) { // Count number of config fields for the group in TABLE_CONFIG worksheet
      if (configRow[3] === groupUUID && configRow[2] !== "") {
        configFields = configFields + 1;
      }
    })
    Logger.log("There are " + configFields + " config fields.");

    // Generate table structure
    table = generateMatrix(uniqueInstanceRows + 1, configFields, "");

    // Fill first column in results table with unique Instance Ids
    for (i = 0; i < Unique_List.length; i++) {
      table[i][0] = Unique_List[i];
    }

    // Generate a table to store Instance Id / File Id pairs 
    pairsTable = generateMatrix(Unique_List.length, 2, "");
    values.forEach(function (row) {
      for (i = 0; i < Unique_List.length; i++) {
        if (row[0] === Unique_List[i]) {
          pairsTable[i][0] = Unique_List[i];
          pairsTable[i][1] = row[7];
        }
      }
    })

    // Fill last column in results table with corresponding File Ids
    table.forEach(function (row, index) {
      for (i = 0; i < pairsTable.length; i++) {
        if (row[0] === pairsTable[i][0]) {
          table[index][configFields + 1] = pairsTable[i][1];
        }
      }
    })

    // Populate results table with remaining group field values
    values.forEach(function (row) {
      configValues.forEach(function (configRow) {
        if (row[4] === configRow[0] && configRow[2] !== "") {
          for (i = 0; i <= Unique_List.length; i++) {
            if (row[0] === Unique_List[i]) {
              rowNum = i;
            }
          }
          let val = row[6];
          table[rowNum][configRow[2]] = val;
        }
      })
    })
    // Return results table
    return table;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Is the function actually slow? You seem to be using arrays, which means you already crossed the biggest tortoise trap.  After that it's basic js optimization. It's still unclear to me, on the surface, what's the input and what's the expected output with each function. Your question maybe better suited to [codereview.se]. Things I'll note `unique` can be rewritten with `Set`, which has better support for unique data. If anything, I'd want to change the spreadsheet/data flow to not call the custom function 100 times. I'd also make use of `Cache` service to avoid recalculating the same input.

Comment: [Edit] to show how you're calling each function and crop the screenshots to only show the data(or remove it completely as  you're already showing  table). It seems you're calling `=func(A1)` for each row. If that's the case, consider rewriting it to accept arrays like: `=func(A1:A100)`

Comment: @TheMaster The getTable() function is only being called once for each 'RESULTS_' worksheet. However the spreadsheet contains 50-100 of those worksheets and changing that usage pattern isn't feasible at the moment, as there are many subsequent calculations performed on the results table data.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `onEdit` trigger be a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you would need a custom function for this when plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas seem to suffice. Try `query()` with a `pivot` clause, like this:

`=query(INPUT!A1:K, "select A, max(G), H where I = 'Pilot' group by A, H pivot D", 1)`

`=query(INPUT!A1:K, "select A, max(G), H where I = 'Co-Pilot' group by A, H pivot D", 1)`

These formulas exactly match the custom function results you show, and they should run much faster.

To reorder the data so that it falls into the column numbers given in the `TABLE_CONFIG` sheet, put the first `query()` formula in a new sheet in cell `query!A1`, and put these formulas in yet another sheet:

cell `A1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Instance Id", 
    iferror( 
      vlookup( 
        sequence(1, max(TABLE_CONFIG!C2:C4) - 1, 2), 
        { TABLE_CONFIG!C2:C, TABLE_CONFIG!B2:B }, 
        2, false 
      ) 
    ), 
    "File Id" 
  } 
)
```

cell `A2`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    hlookup( 
      A1:I1, 
      query!A1:E, 
      sequence(counta(query!A2:A), 1, 2), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The formulas can be put together so that no helper sheet is needed, but that is left as an exercise for the reader. This is just to show that the data *can* be aggregated using plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas without resorting to scripting.

Comment: I need results ordered by the "Desired table field column" from the 'TABLE_CONFIG' sheet. Sorry my sample data is oversimplified. Imagine that the "Desired table field column" values for the 3 fields were 1, 10 and 20 (rather than 1, 2 and 3). The result table should place Field 1's value in the first column after the Instance Id column as shown in the example, however Field 2's value should appear in the 10th column after the Instance Id column and Field 3's value should appear in the 20th column after the Instance Id column. And then the File Id value should always appear in the last column.

Comment: If I enhance the 'INPUT' sheet to include a new column with the "Desired table field column" for each Field Id, can the query be re-written to consider this value and use it to write results in the correct column (and then always put File Id at the end)?

Comment: Edited the answer to re-order columns per `TABLE_CONFIG`.

Comment: This is working and early testing indicates it will be much quicker. Are you able to provide any tips for combining the formulas so that no helper sheet is needed? Once I can finalize my prototype, I will accept this answer.

Comment: This question is about performance. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). You may want to post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Using this nifty project [AlaSQLGS](https://github.com/contributorpw/alasqlgs)~

We can use [AlaSQL](https://github.com/AlaSQL/alasql/wiki) to simplify a lot of data manipulation functions that (imo) would be better done in a database than javascript/appscript.

Here's an example that you could modify that uses your data:

```
const alasql = AlaSQLGS.load()

function Update_Results() {
  const groupUUID = '91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7';
  const role = 'Pilot';
  const inputSheetName = 'INPUT';
  const outputSheetName = 'RESULTS_Pilot';

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName(inputSheetName);
  const outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName(outputSheetName)
  
  let data = inputSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  data.shift() // Remove column names~
  
  // Create a Table and insert values into it.
  // I use \` so often, because you have Spaces and illegal sql column names.
  // Note that these are backticks, not single quotes.
  alasql(`
    CREATE TABLE data (
      \`Instance Id\` STRING,
      \`Group Id\` STRING,
      \`Field name\` STRING,
      \`Field Id\` STRING,
      \`Value\` INT,
      \`File Id\` STRING,
      \`Role\` STRING
    );
    SELECT [0] AS \`Instance Id\`
         , [2] AS \`Group Id\`
         , [3] AS \`Field name\`
         , [4] AS \`Field Id\`
         , [6] AS \`Value\`
         , [7] AS \`File Id\`
         , [8] AS \`Role\`
    INTO data
    FROM ?;
  `, [data])

  // Query the Table
  // MATRIX gives us an Array of Arrays instead of an Array of Objects.
  let output = alasql(`
    SELECT MATRIX
           \`Instance Id\`
         , \`Field name\` 
         , \`File Id\`
         , [Value]
      FROM data
     PIVOT (MAX([Value]) FOR \`Field name\`)
     WHERE \`Group Id\` = ?
       AND \`Role\` = ?
  `, [groupUUID, role]);
  
  // Add Column Names
  output.unshift(['Instance Id', 'File Id', ...output[0].slice(2).map((x,i) => `Field ${i+1}`)])
  
  // Insert the result into the sheet
  outputSheet.clearContents()
  outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);

  Logger.log(output)
}
```

Logger Output:

```
[[Instance Id, File Id, Field 1, Field 2, Field 3],
 [Instance1A, Pilot_File, 100.0, 200.0, 300.0],
 [Instance1B, Pilot_File, 110.0, 220.0, 330.0]]
```

GSheet Output:

| Instance Id | File Id | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance1A | Pilot_File | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| Instance1B | Pilot_File | 110 | 220 | 330 |