# How can I combine a Google Sheets query formula with arrayFormula formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

Code from @doubleunary's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958444/20079006) to: [How can I improve the performance of this Google Sheets custom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73840263/how-can-i-improve-the-performance-of-this-google-sheets-custom-function)

My 'query' sheet has a query formula to filter an 'INPUT' sheet. The query is:

```
=query(INPUT!A1:K, "select A, max(G), H where I = 'Pilot' group by A, H pivot D", 1)
```

The 'INPUT' sheet values are:

| Instance Id | Group name | Group Id | Field name | Field Id | Type | Value | File Id | Role | Concatenated Id | VLookup value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance1A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 1 | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | CURRENCY | 100 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffcInstance1A | 100 |
| Instance1A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 2 | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | CURRENCY | 200 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8eInstance1A | 200 |
| Instance1A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 3 | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | CURRENCY | 300 | Pilot_File | Pilot | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260dInstance1A | 300 |
| Instance1B | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 1 | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | CURRENCY | 110 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffcInstance1B | 110 |
| Instance1B | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 2 | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | CURRENCY | 220 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8eInstance1B | 220 |
| Instance1B | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 3 | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | CURRENCY | 330 | Pilot_File | Pilot | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260dInstance1B | 330 |
| Instance2A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 1 | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | CURRENCY | 1000 | Co-PIlot_File | Co-Pilot | 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffcInstance2A | 1000 |
| Instance2A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 2 | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | CURRENCY | 2000 | Co-PIlot_File | Co-Pilot | 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8eInstance2A | 2000 |
| Instance2A | Widgets | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 | Field 3 | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | CURRENCY | 3000 | Co-PIlot_File | Co-Pilot | ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260dInstance2A | 3000 |

Which gives the following result on the 'query' sheet:

| Instance Id | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | File Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance1A | 100 | 200 | 300 | Pilot_File |
| Instance1B | 110 | 220 | 330 | Pilot_File |

Another 'RESULTS_PILOT' sheet uses two arrayFormula formulas to format the 'query' sheet values into a table with values placed in specific columns according to a 'TABLE_CONFIG' sheet. The formulas are:

cell `A1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Instance Id", 
    iferror( 
      vlookup( 
        sequence(1, max(TABLE_CONFIG!C2:C4) - 1, 2), 
        { TABLE_CONFIG!C2:C, TABLE_CONFIG!B2:B }, 
        2, false 
      ) 
    ), 
    "File Id" 
  } 
)
```

cell `A2`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    hlookup( 
      A1:I1, 
      query!A1:E, 
      sequence(counta(query!A2:A), 1, 2), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

The 'TABLE_CONFIG' sheet is:

| Field Id | Description | Desired table field column | Group Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09456c1a-abb4-4e81-94bd-7ce4c88afffc | Field 1 | 1 | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 |
| 474f6395-83a7-4c2b-aa5a-ceb00e200f8e | Field 2 | 3 | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 |
| ac64e001-fe85-400a-92e4-69cebf1c260d | Field 3 | 5 | 91c7db0a-c52a-407d-869a-af8ba8bf8ba7 |

So the table on the 'RESULTS_PILOT' sheet appears like:

| Instance Id | Field 1 |  | Field 2 |  | Field 3 | File Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance1A | 100 |  | 200 |  | 300 | Pilot_File |
| Instance1B | 110 |  | 220 |  | 330 | Pilot_File |

Is there a way to combine the query with the arrayFormula formulas on the 'RESULTS_PILOT' sheet, so that the 'query' sheet is not required?

Comment: It looks like you copied the code from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, y, {y; IFERROR(HLOOKUP(y, x, 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTA(QUERY(x, "offset 1", )), 1, 2), ))}) 
 (QUERY(INPUT!A1:K, "select A, max(G), H where I = 'Pilot' group by A, H pivot D", 1), 
 {"Instance Id", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(1, MAX(TABLE_CONFIG!C2:C4)-1, 2), 
 {TABLE_CONFIG!C2:C, TABLE_CONFIG!B2:B }, 2, )), "File Id"}))
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly on the sample 'INPUT' data. However I should have explained that my real world 'INPUT' data is mixed format (Text, Number, Date, etc.). It is written to the 'INPUT' sheet via the API with valueInputOption set as "USER_ENTERED". The query formula seems to convert numbers to strings, which breaks subsequent calculations on the values.

Comment: @blade_runner https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG0hY.png