# Can this Google Sheets query formula be modified to work with mixed format values?

Tags: google-sheets

Sample Google Sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xdop5kgB5ON6fVJoYT1sHYQ6fxzSdeu-5rG6Qnr8uIo/edit?usp=sharing)

By adapting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73981319/20079006) from @player0 to [How can I combine a Google Sheets query formula with arrayFormula formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980769/how-can-i-combine-a-google-sheets-query-formula-with-arrayformula-formulas), I have this query:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(x, y, {y; IFERROR(HLOOKUP(y, x, SEQUENCE(COUNTA(QUERY(x, "offset 1", )), 1, 2), ))}) (QUERY(INPUT!A1:K, "select A, max(G), H where C = '7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10' and I = 'Pilot' group by A, H pivot D", 1), {"Instance Id", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(1, 9, 7), {TABLE_CONFIG!C2:C, TABLE_CONFIG!F2:F }, 2, )), "File Id"}))
```

which uses data from the 'INPUT' sheet: (sorry about the length, I understand that query determines the most common value format, so I wanted to provide a representative data set)

| Instance Id | Section Name | Section Id | Field name | Section field Id | Type | Value | File Id | Role | Input Item Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance_A | For | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For 28 pip | 5B77725B43E4-Ee18-7E04-450C-6F322F4A | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 5B77725B43E4-Ee18-7E04-450C-6F322F4AInstance_A | FALSE |
| Instance_A | For | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For 28 E | 95Bfe351F32E-E689-22B4-2C4E-D2453D2B | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 95Bfe351F32E-E689-22B4-2C4E-D2453D2BInstance_A | FALSE |
| Instance_A | For | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For 16 | 8Abb0E9D730A-776B-E714-9B6C-6449Ba3E | CURRENCY | 2300 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 8Abb0E9D730A-776B-E714-9B6C-6449Ba3EInstance_A | 2300 |
| Instance_A | For | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For 18 | C38Eec9Df1C4-0A98-30C4-2A20-6222F429 | CURRENCY | 700 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | C38Eec9Df1C4-0A98-30C4-2A20-6222F429Instance_A | 700 |
| Instance_A | For | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For 28 ceep | 14D14Bcbc72E-C8B9-04E4-Fd45-9Be7Fe3F | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 14D14Bcbc72E-C8B9-04E4-Fd45-9Be7Fe3FInstance_A | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH principal | 16Ca8308B756-F909-E244-5802-019F647A | PICKLIST | Yes | Pilot_File | Pilot | 16Ca8308B756-F909-E244-5802-019F647AInstance_1 | Yes |
| Instance_1 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH type | 4D5B56E0C54F-Be2A-14C4-9Bc9-4D769865 | PICKLIST | unit | Pilot_File | Pilot | 4D5B56E0C54F-Be2A-14C4-9Bc9-4D769865Instance_1 | unit |
| Instance_1 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH this year | 6C80F9B3B190-01F8-8Ec4-944A-2323101C | PICKLIST | Yes | Pilot_File | Pilot | 6C80F9B3B190-01F8-8Ec4-944A-2323101CInstance_1 | Yes |
| Instance_1 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH address | Dafc339Ad2Af-08Fa-4094-B111-38Cfc989 | PICKLIST | Use mail | Pilot_File | Pilot | Dafc339Ad2Af-08Fa-4094-B111-38Cfc989Instance_1 | Use mail |
| Instance_1 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH who | 6A42F461F7Bc-0F68-4444-495A-F7Dce6E4 | PICKLIST | me and co-pilot | Pilot_File | Pilot | 6A42F461F7Bc-0F68-4444-495A-F7Dce6E4Instance_1 | me and co-pilot |
| Instance_1 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH better | Da468Ed1C38C-7029-8924-1507-Eefe2F97 | PICKLIST | Yes | Pilot_File | Pilot | Da468Ed1C38C-7029-8924-1507-Eefe2F97Instance_1 | Yes |
| Instance_1 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH disable | 33Ab5D3F22B9-Ae5A-2634-0Ffa-4E437000 | PICKLIST | Yes | Pilot_File | Pilot | 33Ab5D3F22B9-Ae5A-2634-0Ffa-4E437000Instance_1 | Yes |
| Instance_1 | Your info | 90175471-fa8c-4123-b7d9-625e0e5fe1c6 | Sine | Af5A56026066-6A38-F924-4B68-A5495366 | STRING | 333333333 | Pilot_File | Pilot | Af5A56026066-6A38-F924-4B68-A5495366Instance_1 | 333333333 |
| Instance_1 | Your info | 90175471-fa8c-4123-b7d9-625e0e5fe1c6 | Outer | 369D5E00925B-60Cb-7924-D0Eb-7B10F916 | PICKLIST | Yes | Pilot_File | Pilot | 369D5E00925B-60Cb-7924-D0Eb-7B10F916Instance_1 | Yes |
| Instance_1 | Status | 96f925f0-1f47-400c-8985-8264ce8480d5 | Marstat | 98F8D8Df15Cf-3C5B-1224-B985-46Fc8Dc0 | PICKLIST | Mar | Pilot_File | Pilot | 98F8D8Df15Cf-3C5B-1224-B985-46Fc8Dc0Instance_1 | Mar |
| Instance_1 | Arriving | de578083-7194-4844-ac64-82c16d3c0d1a | To | A1Ddbb67C6Ed-31C9-A434-5Bf2-1A81Eef4 | PICKLIST | No | Pilot_File | Pilot | A1Ddbb67C6Ed-31C9-A434-5Bf2-1A81Eef4Instance_1 | No |
| Instance_1 | Arriving | de578083-7194-4844-ac64-82c16d3c0d1a | Away | Bf7Ecaaa2397-E398-Cfe4-F9B0-136E325F | PICKLIST | No | Pilot_File | Pilot | Bf7Ecaaa2397-E398-Cfe4-F9B0-136E325FInstance_1 | No |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam O | B5A76D33Ae9E-F5Ca-A554-2D13-4Bd03692 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Pilot_File | Pilot | B5A76D33Ae9E-F5Ca-A554-2D13-4Bd03692Instance_1 | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam child | Dd4028Face79-2258-Eb14-F8F8-1D722Fa8 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Pilot_File | Pilot | Dd4028Face79-2258-Eb14-F8F8-1D722Fa8Instance_1 | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam full | 399F13943444-Dc4A-2Fd4-F73E-0877E29C | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Pilot_File | Pilot | 399F13943444-Dc4A-2Fd4-F73E-0877E29CInstance_1 | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam don | 1540E97B2Bf2-8C4B-4F94-258C-Da495D11 | BOOLEAN | TRUE | Pilot_File | Pilot | 1540E97B2Bf2-8C4B-4F94-258C-Da495D11Instance_1 | TRUE |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam half | 76Db2B73D7Ee-Dcca-A214-A46D-E2197Eb9 | BOOLEAN | TRUE | Pilot_File | Pilot | 76Db2B73D7Ee-Dcca-A214-A46D-E2197Eb9Instance_1 | TRUE |
| Instance_1 | Eligibility | 797066f6-ef67-4b12-abcb-827a46b3ef88 | Officer | A1F459120021-Bca9-8Ae4-3531-9B94E358 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Pilot_File | Pilot | A1F459120021-Bca9-8Ae4-3531-9B94E358Instance_1 | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | Eligibility | 797066f6-ef67-4b12-abcb-827a46b3ef88 | Confin | 5De2C719Bd5A-6A6A-51F4-733A-00Ed2311 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Pilot_File | Pilot | 5De2C719Bd5A-6A6A-51F4-733A-00Ed2311Instance_1 | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | Your info | 90175471-fa8c-4123-b7d9-625e0e5fe1c6 | Birth | 231124B9A0Be-3Bc8-C684-E82C-3Dad8183 | DATE | 6641 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 231124B9A0Be-3Bc8-C684-E82C-3Dad8183Instance_1 | 6641 |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam med | 2F583Bd47052-A418-3Bb4-B4E0-1C5C3933 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Pilot_File | Pilot | 2F583Bd47052-A418-3Bb4-B4E0-1C5C3933Instance_1 | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Fname | E4A3E63Fde3B-490A-A664-765E-C0A61Bf3 | STRING | Dania | Pilot_File | Pilot | E4A3E63Fde3B-490A-A664-765E-C0A61Bf3Instance_1 | Dania |
| Instance_1 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Address | C9E9Cc567A9C-5Eda-6Cf4-2D53-73E1F4Ec | STRING | Rd5 | Pilot_File | Pilot | C9E9Cc567A9C-5Eda-6Cf4-2D53-73E1F4EcInstance_1 | Rd5 |
| Instance_1 | Resider | c9affc56-3771-4e0f-b756-6790ff843b0b | Prov | B39Df12A5E1F-3D0A-20A4-Dac1-6E147518 | PICKLIST | ON | Pilot_File | Pilot | B39Df12A5E1F-3D0A-20A4-Dac1-6E147518Instance_1 | ON |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam care | D519Ebdc0503-A9Fa-7E84-2A51-E0E6B22B | BOOLEAN | TRUE | Pilot_File | Pilot | D519Ebdc0503-A9Fa-7E84-2A51-E0E6B22BInstance_1 | TRUE |
| Instance_1 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | City | 2B40E2762Abd-33Bb-1704-0D98-F873Fd14 | STRING | Almountain | Pilot_File | Pilot | 2B40E2762Abd-33Bb-1704-0D98-F873Fd14Instance_1 | Almountain |
| Instance_1 | Status | c30de961-6ad0-4c4d-8ee3-d59f5de4d60c | Pre-part | 7Bf540B271D6-9B5B-8Cc4-Eb93-8Ac9Bd06 | PICKLIST | Yes | Pilot_File | Pilot | 7Bf540B271D6-9B5B-8Cc4-Eb93-8Ac9Bd06Instance_1 | Yes |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam work | C363836F96Be-Ab4B-7184-4C3C-0C10A84E | BOOLEAN | TRUE | Pilot_File | Pilot | C363836F96Be-Ab4B-7184-4C3C-0C10A84EInstance_1 | TRUE |
| Instance_1 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Lname | 41Eef2B4849A-A708-F464-12Ac-B64B39D0 | STRING | Feeve | Pilot_File | Pilot | 41Eef2B4849A-A708-F464-12Ac-B64B39D0Instance_1 | Feeve |
| Instance_1 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Prove | B2E650010330-E0E9-5Ac4-2C89-1B62A777 | PICKLIST | ON | Pilot_File | Pilot | B2E650010330-E0E9-5Ac4-2C89-1B62A777Instance_1 | ON |
| Instance_1 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam dis | 85E9Afea6C67-3E49-C524-144E-3E70B77B | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Pilot_File | Pilot | 85E9Afea6C67-3E49-C524-144E-3E70B77BInstance_1 | FALSE |
| Instance_1 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Post | 6A54507Cb8C0-6D8B-08E4-2Fdc-Faf1C495 | STRING | K2K1B3 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 6A54507Cb8C0-6D8B-08E4-2Fdc-Faf1C495Instance_1 | K2K1B3 |
| Instance_2 | Disabler | db8f65e9-065d-41cb-96f3-36ee7bd892cf | Cred | F301E437Eacb-Ce09-80E4-713C-61F85A09 | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | F301E437Eacb-Ce09-80E4-713C-61F85A09Instance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH Principal | 16Ca8308B756-F909-E244-5802-019F647A | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 16Ca8308B756-F909-E244-5802-019F647AInstance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH type | 4D5B56E0C54F-Be2A-14C4-9Bc9-4D769865 | PICKLIST | unit | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 4D5B56E0C54F-Be2A-14C4-9Bc9-4D769865Instance_2 | unit |
| Instance_2 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH this year | 6C80F9B3B190-01F8-8Ec4-944A-2323101C | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 6C80F9B3B190-01F8-8Ec4-944A-2323101CInstance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH address | Dafc339Ad2Af-08Fa-4094-B111-38Cfc989 | PICKLIST | Use mail | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | Dafc339Ad2Af-08Fa-4094-B111-38Cfc989Instance_2 | Use mail |
| Instance_2 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH who | 6A42F461F7Bc-0F68-4444-495A-F7Dce6E4 | PICKLIST | me and co-pilot | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 6A42F461F7Bc-0F68-4444-495A-F7Dce6E4Instance_2 | me and co-pilot |
| Instance_2 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH better | Da468Ed1C38C-7029-8924-1507-Eefe2F97 | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | Da468Ed1C38C-7029-8924-1507-Eefe2F97Instance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | First timer | a298166f-2c2f-4461-bba8-2b6fe1b730d7 | FTH disable | 33Ab5D3F22B9-Ae5A-2634-0Ffa-4E437000 | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 33Ab5D3F22B9-Ae5A-2634-0Ffa-4E437000Instance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | Your info | 90175471-fa8c-4123-b7d9-625e0e5fe1c6 | Sine | Af5A56026066-6A38-F924-4B68-A5495366 | STRING | 555555555 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | Af5A56026066-6A38-F924-4B68-A5495366Instance_2 | 555555555 |
| Instance_2 | Your info | 90175471-fa8c-4123-b7d9-625e0e5fe1c6 | Outer | 369D5E00925B-60Cb-7924-D0Eb-7B10F916 | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 369D5E00925B-60Cb-7924-D0Eb-7B10F916Instance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | Status | c30de961-6ad0-4c4d-8ee3-d59f5de4d60c | Marstat | 98F8D8Df15Cf-3C5B-1224-B985-46Fc8Dc0 | PICKLIST | Mar | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 98F8D8Df15Cf-3C5B-1224-B985-46Fc8Dc0Instance_2 | Mar |
| Instance_2 | Arriving | de578083-7194-4844-ac64-82c16d3c0d1a | To | A1Ddbb67C6Ed-31C9-A434-5Bf2-1A81Eef4 | PICKLIST | No | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | A1Ddbb67C6Ed-31C9-A434-5Bf2-1A81Eef4Instance_2 | No |
| Instance_2 | Arriving | de578083-7194-4844-ac64-82c16d3c0d1a | Away | Bf7Ecaaa2397-E398-Cfe4-F9B0-136E325F | PICKLIST | No | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | Bf7Ecaaa2397-E398-Cfe4-F9B0-136E325FInstance_2 | No |
| Instance_2 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam child | Dd4028Face79-2258-Eb14-F8F8-1D722Fa8 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | Dd4028Face79-2258-Eb14-F8F8-1D722Fa8Instance_2 | FALSE |
| Instance_2 | Eligibility | 797066f6-ef67-4b12-abcb-827a46b3ef88 | Officer | A1F459120021-Bca9-8Ae4-3531-9B94E358 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | A1F459120021-Bca9-8Ae4-3531-9B94E358Instance_2 | FALSE |
| Instance_2 | Eligibility | 797066f6-ef67-4b12-abcb-827a46b3ef88 | Confin | 5De2C719Bd5A-6A6A-51F4-733A-00Ed2311 | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 5De2C719Bd5A-6A6A-51F4-733A-00Ed2311Instance_2 | FALSE |
| Instance_2 | Fighter | e6aab418-5963-4e78-a698-39fac82ef10d | Vol | B6Ef678E8E12-33C8-1704-69Fa-A55A0537 | PICKLIST | Fighter | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | B6Ef678E8E12-33C8-1704-69Fa-A55A0537Instance_2 | Fighter |
| Instance_2 | Your info | 90175471-fa8c-4123-b7d9-625e0e5fe1c6 | Birth | 231124B9A0Be-3Bc8-C684-E82C-3Dad8183 | DATE | 7372 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 231124B9A0Be-3Bc8-C684-E82C-3Dad8183Instance_2 | 7372 |
| Instance_2 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Fname | E4A3E63Fde3B-490A-A664-765E-C0A61Bf3 | STRING | Jim | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | E4A3E63Fde3B-490A-A664-765E-C0A61Bf3Instance_2 | Jim |
| Instance_2 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Address | C9E9Cc567A9C-5Eda-6Cf4-2D53-73E1F4Ec | STRING | Rd5 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | C9E9Cc567A9C-5Eda-6Cf4-2D53-73E1F4EcInstance_2 | Rd5 |
| Instance_2 | Fighter | e6aab418-5963-4e78-a698-39fac82ef10d | 200h | 7060F7C3A034-D0C8-Bea4-3B7F-958Abef0 | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 7060F7C3A034-D0C8-Bea4-3B7F-958Abef0Instance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | Resider | c9affc56-3771-4e0f-b756-6790ff843b0b | Prov | B39Df12A5E1F-3D0A-20A4-Dac1-6E147518 | PICKLIST | ON | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | B39Df12A5E1F-3D0A-20A4-Dac1-6E147518Instance_2 | ON |
| Instance_2 | Status | c30de961-6ad0-4c4d-8ee3-d59f5de4d60c | Pre-part | 7Bf540B271D6-9B5B-8Cc4-Eb93-8Ac9Bd06 | PICKLIST | Yes | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 7Bf540B271D6-9B5B-8Cc4-Eb93-8Ac9Bd06Instance_2 | Yes |
| Instance_2 | Optimization | e3b81931-0333-4a9e-b8d0-f9526d6b258d | Clam work | C363836F96Be-Ab4B-7184-4C3C-0C10A84E | BOOLEAN | FALSE | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | C363836F96Be-Ab4B-7184-4C3C-0C10A84EInstance_2 | FALSE |
| Instance_2 | Address | f0b03873-1fb9-4df6-9aa0-9509859997ad | Lname | 41Eef2B4849A-A708-F464-12Ac-B64B39D0 | STRING | Feeve | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 41Eef2B4849A-A708-F464-12Ac-B64B39D0Instance_2 | Feeve |
| Instance_B | Rasp | 4a8d742a-8dfc-468d-80ba-55521dff3af5 | Rasp 30 | 85Fd1690C80D-9A8A-1Ef4-9Fde-4A4D0677 | CURRENCY | 500 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 85Fd1690C80D-9A8A-1Ef4-9Fde-4A4D0677Instance_B | 500 |
| Instance_B | Rasp | 4a8d742a-8dfc-468d-80ba-55521dff3af5 | Rasp 22 | 2C03A4B809F7-9139-D924-Edae-6Df67E2C | CURRENCY | 2905 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 2C03A4B809F7-9139-D924-Edae-6Df67E2CInstance_B | 2905 |
| Instance_B | Rasp | 4a8d742a-8dfc-468d-80ba-55521dff3af5 | Rasp 16 | C798E0De8773-5Dea-B594-2C2C-Bc0774Ca | CURRENCY | 4600 | Pilot_File | Pilot | C798E0De8773-5Dea-B594-2C2C-Bc0774CaInstance_B | 4600 |
| Instance_C | Forty wait | 45b235d0-f923-4bc5-875b-3eea18b7d1de | Fl28 | 24E38C754E91-248B-1C94-958E-7C6A40C5 | CURRENCY | 17696 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 24E38C754E91-248B-1C94-958E-7C6A40C5Instance_C | 17696 |
| Instance_C | Forty wait | 45b235d0-f923-4bc5-875b-3eea18b7d1de | fw040 | E73E59F3C656-Abda-6144-A680-D1A630Da | CURRENCY | 10880 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | E73E59F3C656-Abda-6144-A680-D1A630DaInstance_C | 10880 |
| Instance_C | Forty wait | 45b235d0-f923-4bc5-875b-3eea18b7d1de | fw080 | 58F455359409-939A-5224-229F-0903794B | CURRENCY | 5312 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 58F455359409-939A-5224-229F-0903794BInstance_C | 5312 |
| Instance_C | Forty wait | 45b235d0-f923-4bc5-875b-3eea18b7d1de | fw440 | 2F4384Aa9068-Ec18-Ec34-0340-Df7883Ef | CURRENCY | 8790 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 2F4384Aa9068-Ec18-Ec34-0340-Df7883EfInstance_C | 8790 |
| Instance_C | Forty wait | 45b235d0-f923-4bc5-875b-3eea18b7d1de | fw360 | 7C289B99D923-3C1B-7444-95E9-0Ca3E514 | CURRENCY | 1504 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 7C289B99D923-3C1B-7444-95E9-0Ca3E514Instance_C | 1504 |
| Instance_D | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray205_Cfa76928Fb5F-1218-56D4-3Aff-58E07812 | Cfa76928Fb5F-1218-56D4-3Aff-58E07812 | CURRENCY | 500 | Pilot_File | Pilot | Cfa76928Fb5F-1218-56D4-3Aff-58E07812Instance_D | 500 |
| Instance_D | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray01s_057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2 | 057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2 | PICKLIST | Fed | Pilot_File | Pilot | 057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2Instance_D | Fed |
| Instance_D | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray boolean_230Eb5Bb9895-2Eca-B454-5209-71E27218 | 230Eb5Bb9895-2Eca-B454-5209-71E27218 | BOOLEAN | TRUE | Pilot_File | Pilot | 230Eb5Bb9895-2Eca-B454-5209-71E27218Instance_D | TRUE |
| Instance_D | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray date_C07139810A05-C4B9-D494-2D66-4Baa27Af | C07139810A05-C4B9-D494-2D66-4Baa27Af | DATE | 7372 | Pilot_File | Pilot | C07139810A05-C4B9-D494-2D66-4Baa27AfInstance_D | 7372 |
| Instance_E | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray022_4F43D278237D-D75B-Af14-F95C-A07F66F7 | 4F43D278237D-D75B-Af14-F95C-A07F66F7 | CURRENCY | 7000 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 4F43D278237D-D75B-Af14-F95C-A07F66F7Instance_E | 7000 |
| Instance_E | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray024_C64C5A254720-8Fa9-3824-98B6-4F41618F | C64C5A254720-8Fa9-3824-98B6-4F41618F | CURRENCY | 4350 | Pilot_File | Pilot | C64C5A254720-8Fa9-3824-98B6-4F41618FInstance_E | 4350 |
| Instance_E | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray016_2C1F1F4F5D4A-C4Ea-5224-5878-A54Be7Cd | 2C1F1F4F5D4A-C4Ea-5224-5878-A54Be7Cd | CURRENCY | 9615 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 2C1F1F4F5D4A-C4Ea-5224-5878-A54Be7CdInstance_E | 9615 |
| Instance_E | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray018_38623C1B3Cbd-2098-9594-De57-1Ea73F92 | 38623C1B3Cbd-2098-9594-De57-1Ea73F92 | CURRENCY | 12750 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 38623C1B3Cbd-2098-9594-De57-1Ea73F92Instance_E | 12750 |
| Instance_E | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray01s057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2 | 057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2 | PICKLIST | Fed | Pilot_File | Pilot | 057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2Instance_E | Fed |
| Instance_E | Foray | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray046_B1Ea4005125B-F318-D0D4-Ef9D-C0E2669D | B1Ea4005125B-F318-D0D4-Ef9D-C0E2669D | CURRENCY | 187 | Pilot_File | Pilot | B1Ea4005125B-F318-D0D4-Ef9D-C0E2669DInstance_E | 187 |
| Instance_F | Tree | 578146d5-5bce-4927-9880-1233d78d05fb | Tree26 | 9073C88A8A56-0099-C224-E841-E674Da36 | CURRENCY | 17800 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 9073C88A8A56-0099-C224-E841-E674Da36Instance_F | 17800 |
| Instance_G | Foreign | f017da6d-af6d-4491-84f2-34266a90639e | Typ | Dfaf52Cf4B32-E92B-6804-31Be-0E1874C0 | PICKLIST | Sec ben | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | Dfaf52Cf4B32-E92B-6804-31Be-0E1874C0Instance_G | Sec ben |
| Instance_G | Foreign | f017da6d-af6d-4491-84f2-34266a90639e | Amt | C6Ca3Edcdbcb-Ae4A-D864-8C7A-7B138A4E | CURRENCY | 2000 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | C6Ca3Edcdbcb-Ae4A-D864-8C7A-7B138A4EInstance_G | 2000 |
| Instance_G | Foreign | f017da6d-af6d-4491-84f2-34266a90639e | Ency | E73F143Eca75-D6A9-1054-0E06-503918Ec | PICKLIST | CAD | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | E73F143Eca75-D6A9-1054-0E06-503918EcInstance_G | CAD |
| Instance_G | Foreign | f017da6d-af6d-4491-84f2-34266a90639e | Sub | B2E413C14B1D-F1B9-9A94-6687-A85Dae60 | PICKLIST | No | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | B2E413C14B1D-F1B9-9A94-6687-A85Dae60Instance_G | No |
| Instance_H | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | L26 | 2A78A51A6189-Ff1A-0934-Ff0A-6B8Fb6Da | CURRENCY | 38100 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 2A78A51A6189-Ff1A-0934-Ff0A-6B8Fb6DaInstance_H | 38100 |
| Instance_H | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | Fl96 | Ae973C0Bf9A1-69D8-1D24-8F55-265799A2 | CURRENCY | 30373.95 | Pilot_File | Pilot | Ae973C0Bf9A1-69D8-1D24-8F55-265799A2Instance_H | 30373.95 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | Fl73left | 6893C192E6D3-1459-C694-A38E-E41D2D3F | CURRENCY | 2925 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 6893C192E6D3-1459-C694-A38E-E41D2D3FInstance_I | 2925 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | T1600 | 669E243F3Ca5-9C88-40C4-2Cc8-2575Ae08 | CURRENCY | 8662 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 669E243F3Ca5-9C88-40C4-2Cc8-2575Ae08Instance_I | 8662 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | T0100 | 819A6A3Fd047-5Dd8-0534-B7Fa-4A7D3Ef9 | CURRENCY | 7713 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 819A6A3Fd047-5Dd8-0534-B7Fa-4A7D3Ef9Instance_I | 7713 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | T6000 | 2A78A51A6189-Ff1A-0934-Ff0A-6B8Fb6Da | CURRENCY | 19500 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 2A78A51A6189-Ff1A-0934-Ff0A-6B8Fb6DaInstance_I | 19500 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | T3000 | 22B0F0242B1B-3Bda-6Bd4-4F2C-9Dfeda7B | CURRENCY | 13808 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 22B0F0242B1B-3Bda-6Bd4-4F2C-9Dfeda7BInstance_I | 13808 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | T3122 | 3Fba85D18287-464A-7804-A3Ba-C8F8Ceae | CURRENCY | 3000 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 3Fba85D18287-464A-7804-A3Ba-C8F8CeaeInstance_I | 3000 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | T3127 | 590F16B901C5-Fed8-29B4-9Cc8-24168010 | CURRENCY | 2500 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 590F16B901C5-Fed8-29B4-9Cc8-24168010Instance_I | 2500 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | Fl96 | Ae973C0Bf9A1-69D8-1D24-8F55-265799A2 | CURRENCY | 28721 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | Ae973C0Bf9A1-69D8-1D24-8F55-265799A2Instance_I | 28721 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | T3140 | 685B0Da29907-1C4A-Eff4-58Ee-1A7F49A3 | CURRENCY | 1700 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 685B0Da29907-1C4A-Eff4-58Ee-1A7F49A3Instance_I | 1700 |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | TFname | 27Ea34A4Cb39-A368-6874-D98E-4B40F166 | STRING | Jim | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 27Ea34A4Cb39-A368-6874-D98E-4B40F166Instance_I | Jim |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | TLname | 584C6F427F9D-Bc6A-B984-A523-44E58D77 | STRING | Feeve | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 584C6F427F9D-Bc6A-B984-A523-44E58D77Instance_I | Feeve |
| Instance_I | Tonne | a13b55f1-833b-4425-88d7-989964c35e5e | 33600 | 42F2066Bb452-E279-5E14-66C4-9048E817 | CURRENCY | 19800 | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 42F2066Bb452-E279-5E14-66C4-9048E817Instance_I | 19800 |
| Instance_J | Forest | d20a8fb2-b1b1-4b3d-b77e-07b2f9d7a3ad | Forest18 | 161D32E807E8-A939-4054-5A45-875348E0 | CURRENCY | 3380 | Pilot_File | Pilot | 161D32E807E8-A939-4054-5A45-875348E0Instance_J | 3380 |
| Instance_J | Forest | d20a8fb2-b1b1-4b3d-b77e-07b2f9d7a3ad | Forest21 | B4Dbb1D01E0A-227A-D964-Cc9A-E7A0Ec14 | CURRENCY | 3800 | Pilot_File | Pilot | B4Dbb1D01E0A-227A-D964-Cc9A-E7A0Ec14Instance_J | 3800 |
| Instance_K | Sable | 2ec3def2-8c70-468a-95db-1e92a6c53f7b | Rel | 932D068666B6-F59A-4954-E9Ba-20004Cb4 | PICKLIST | Louse | Pilot_File | Pilot | 932D068666B6-F59A-4954-E9Ba-20004Cb4Instance_K | Louse |
| Instance_L | Sable | 2ec3def2-8c70-468a-95db-1e92a6c53f7b | Rel | 932D068666B6-F59A-4954-E9Ba-20004Cb4 | PICKLIST | My | Co-Pilot_File | Co-Pilot | 932D068666B6-F59A-4954-E9Ba-20004Cb4Instance_L | My |

and the values from the 'TABLE_CONFIG' sheet:

| Section field Id | Field name | Config sequence | Section Id | Section name | Field key and col header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8Abb0E9D730A-776B-E714-9B6C-6449Ba3E | For 16 | 2 | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For | For 16_8Abb0E9D730A-776B-E714-9B6C-6449Ba3E |
| C38Eec9Df1C4-0A98-30C4-2A20-6222F429 | For 18 | 3 | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For | For 18_C38Eec9Df1C4-0A98-30C4-2A20-6222F429 |
| 14D14Bcbc72E-C8B9-04E4-Fd45-9Be7Fe3F | For 28 ceep | 4 | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For | For 28 ceep_14D14Bcbc72E-C8B9-04E4-Fd45-9Be7Fe3F |
| 95Bfe351F32E-E689-22B4-2C4E-D2453D2B | For 28 E | 5 | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For | For 28 E_95Bfe351F32E-E689-22B4-2C4E-D2453D2B |
| 5B77725B43E4-Ee18-7E04-450C-6F322F4A | For 28 pip | 6 | 1a224188-8bed-4f5c-b731-32b98f4290b6 | For | For 28 pip_5B77725B43E4-Ee18-7E04-450C-6F322F4A |
| 2C1F1F4F5D4A-C4Ea-5224-5878-A54Be7Cd | Foray016 | 7 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray016_2C1F1F4F5D4A-C4Ea-5224-5878-A54Be7Cd |
| 38623C1B3Cbd-2098-9594-De57-1Ea73F92 | Foray018 | 8 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray018_38623C1B3Cbd-2098-9594-De57-1Ea73F92 |
| 4F43D278237D-D75B-Af14-F95C-A07F66F7 | Foray022 | 9 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray022_4F43D278237D-D75B-Af14-F95C-A07F66F7 |
| C64C5A254720-8Fa9-3824-98B6-4F41618F | Foray024 | 10 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray024_C64C5A254720-8Fa9-3824-98B6-4F41618F |
| B1Ea4005125B-F318-D0D4-Ef9D-C0E2669D | Foray046 | 11 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray046_B1Ea4005125B-F318-D0D4-Ef9D-C0E2669D |
| 057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2 | Foray01s | 12 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray01s_057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2 |
| Cfa76928Fb5F-1218-56D4-3Aff-58E07812 | Foray205 | 13 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray205_Cfa76928Fb5F-1218-56D4-3Aff-58E07812 |
| 230Eb5Bb9895-2Eca-B454-5209-71E27218 | Foray boolean | 14 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray boolean_230Eb5Bb9895-2Eca-B454-5209-71E27218 |
| C07139810A05-C4B9-D494-2D66-4Baa27Af | Foray date | 15 | 7e053706-1f2b-4397-bf80-b345671d22c10 | Foray | Foray date_C07139810A05-C4B9-D494-2D66-4Baa27Af |

resulting in the following table on the 'PILOT_FORAY' sheet:

| Instance Id | Foray016_2C1F1F4F5D4A-C4Ea-5224-5878-A54Be7Cd | Foray018_38623C1B3Cbd-2098-9594-De57-1Ea73F92 | Foray022_4F43D278237D-D75B-Af14-F95C-A07F66F7 | Foray024_C64C5A254720-8Fa9-3824-98B6-4F41618F | Foray046_B1Ea4005125B-F318-D0D4-Ef9D-C0E2669D | Foray01s_057Bcab44947-9Da9-6D44-52Af-34648Ee2 | Foray205_Cfa76928Fb5F-1218-56D4-3Aff-58E07812 | Foray boolean_230Eb5Bb9895-2Eca-B454-5209-71E27218 | Foray date_C07139810A05-C4B9-D494-2D66-4Baa27Af | File Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Instance_D |  |  |  |  |  | Fed | 500 | TRUE | 1920-03-07 | Pilot_File |
| Instance_E | 9615 | 12750 | 7000 | 4350 | 187 |  |  |  |  | Pilot_File |

The problem I have is that when Number values from 'INPUT' are copied to another cell to be added (or some other calculation), they are not working, like so:

| Sum Foray_016 | Sum Foray_018 | Sum Foray_022 | Sum Foray_024 | Sum Foray_046 | Copy Foray_01s | Eval Foray_boolean | Eval Date | Double Foray_205 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  | Fed | TRUE | 1920-03-07 | 1000 |
| 9615 | 12750 | 7000 | 4350 | 187 |  |  |  | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | Fed_copied | Yes | 1920 | 1000 |

Other value formats from 'INPUT' seem okay; for eaxample, String can be copied, Boolean and Date can be evaluated. If the reference is a formula (i.e. Double Foray_205, above) the Number behaves as a number. However, a simple copy of the value to a new cell does not, as in the first summed columns above showing 0.

Is there a way to modify the query to fix this? I understand that the query function is determining the most common value format and treating all values as such. The query would still need to work if any other format (number, boolean, date, etc.) was the most common in 'INPUT'.

Comment: Create a [mcve].  Don't just copy paste your data. Use example variables  headers `A`,`B`,`C`. Data like simple numbers: `1`,`2`. The example should preferably be  within 4x4 table for input and expected output. Show What you've tried.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562518/query-is-ignoring-string-non-numeric-value (And this is how you should've asked)

Answer (score 0):

if QUERY is not able to evaluate mixed data then the only way how to tackle it is to convert input into plain text. this can be done in 5 ways:

appending trailing empty space:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(A:C&"", "select *", 0))
```

wrapping it into `{}`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:C}, "select *", 0))
```

using formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A:C), "select *", 0))
```

or partial combination. for example, if we know that column B is problematic but A and C are fine and shouldn't be converted we can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:A, TO_TEXT(B:B), C:C}, "select *", 0))
```

or formatting the source range as Plain Text

worth mentioning that either of these top 4 ways you use you will need ARRAYFORMULA wrapping and column references in SQL command needs to be Col1,Col2,Col3 instead of A,B,C

"yes, but I need outputted numeric values for further calculations"

nope, (in 99/100 cases) there is no need to actually have numeric values because by doing the calculation itself will convert automatically the plain text formatting into numeric values. example:

```
="123" + "2"
```

if there is a special case when you totally need numeric values there is IFERROR workaround:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A:C), "select *", 0)*1, 
                      QUERY(TO_TEXT(A:C), "select *", 0)))
```

by repeating the same thing twice this can get really long in some cases but it works. fortunately, this can be nicely refactored with LAMBDA like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LAMBDA(x, IFERROR(x*1, x))
 (QUERY(TO_TEXT(A:C), "select *", 0)))
```

Comment: It would be better if this question was closed and this answer moved [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562518/query-is-ignoring-string-non-numeric-value) as the question there is better and better suited to be a dupe target.

Comment: @TheMaster moved...